# How to browse from one amp page to other?

Tags: amp-html

Let's say user is navigated to one of my AMP page. And now he is clicking on some navigation item which is linking to my other page which also supports AMP. 
Will AMP version of that page will get open or always the normal page?

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

The browser will follow whatever is in the href for the link. If you want the link to go to the AMP version of that page, you have to put the URL for the AMP version of that page in the href. Otherwise, it will go to the normal page.

For example, say you have this link in the page HTML:

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/mypage'>link</a>
```

If you click on this link in an AMP page, it will go to /mypage. If you want it to go to the amp version of the page, you will need to explicitly tell it to go to the amp version of the page:

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/mypage/amp/'>link</a>
```

Depends on what URL structure you use for amp pages. If you're on a CMS, you could add a filter to automatically turn any links in a page into links to the AMP equivalent.

Comment: exactly my answer, mine even has an example

Comment: nogui not exactly your answer, the question was about links in the page which link to other pages on the site which are AMP enabled.

Comment: which again is mentioned in my answer

Comment: When I am using Google search on my mobile and see some amp results, this seems to be working bit differently.
So an amp page is only opened by google results that too with different layover and whenever I am clicking to any internal links, its simply opening  the normal link

Comment: nogui I think he meant with anchor tags, not link tags

Comment: socialGaurav edited my answer to clarify what you should do to make the links in the AMP page go to AMP versions

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linking pages with](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)  guide which addresses your issue:

> In order to solve this problem, we add information about the AMP page
>   to the non-AMP page and vice versa, in the form of  tags in the
>   .

It depends on what you specified in your  [element](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery).
If you open the page whose rel value in the link is `amphtml` like

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

then it will go to the AMP version of that site.

On the other hand if you used rel value of `canonical` like

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

it will go to the normal page.